# How to edit a line (overwright and replace) in Python

Tags: python

I have a file and I need to edit a specific line inside that file.

I need to edit this line:

```
"file:///c:/xxxxxxx/nameList.json#/"
```

into:

```
< xxxx="xxxx://xxxx.com/xxxx//nameList.md">nameList /xxxxxx/
```

How should I do it?

Notice that I need to somehow store the "nameList". I am writing a script and the "nameList" part is differ for different files.

Additional information:

1. I just need to replace whatever in front of "nameList" and whatever after "nameList"...
2. But the string"nameList" is arbitrary for different files. For example, the first file will have nameList1, the second will have nameList2.....etc. I need to keep the nameListX for different files.

Comment: does the `xxxx` come from that same input line?

Comment: xxxx are all different. They are just some unknown characters

Comment: so they don't matter?

Comment: they dont matter. I just need to replace whatever in front of nameList and whatever after nameList....But the string"nameList" is arbitrary for different files. For example the first file I will have nameList1, the second will have nameList2.....etc

Comment: You might want to look into https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub. Without a more defined problem space, it's tough to provide further direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
regex = re.compile("file:///c:/([^/]+)/nameList.json#/")
replacer = lambda g: '< {0}="{0}://{0}.com/{0}//nameList.md">nameList /{0}/'.format(g.groups()[0])

with open("output.txt","w") as f:
    for line in open("input.txt"):
         f.write(re.sub(regex, replacer, line))
```

Maybe ... I don't know what the xxxx in the second one have to do with the xxxx's in the first one...

If you just want the "nameList" part then

```
regex = re.compile("file:///c:/[^/]+/([.]+)\.json#/")
replacer = lambda g: '<xmlns="http://blahblah.com/sub1//{0}.md">{0} /xxxx/'.format(g.groups()[0])

with open("output.txt","w") as f:
    for line in open("input.txt"):
         f.write(re.sub(regex, replacer, line))
```

Comment: I think he's trying to parse out `nameList` and not the `xxxx` values.

Comment: maybe ... I assumed that there was more to it than that ... but from the comments you might be right ...

Comment: that's why I asked first off ;)  Though it actually appears to be a combination of both of our answers.

Comment: Thx for the help:) Sorry I just started learning python. I am also wondering how can I find "file:///c:/([^/]+)/nameList.json#/" this line in my file..I need to find this line first before I replace it..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `xxxx` doesn't matter in either of the cases, AND that each of the inputs are file names without any other `.` besides the extension, this will get your desired output:

```
test = "file:///c:/xxxxxxx/nameList.json#/"
parsed_file = test.split('.')[0].split('/')[-1]
result = """< xxxx="xxxx://xxxx.com/xxxx//{0}.md">{0} /xxxxxx/""".format(parsed_file)
print(result)
```

---

Addressing your comments:

```
test = "file:///c:/xxxxxxx/nameList.json#/"

def replace_text(s):
    parsed_file = test.split('.')[0].split('/')[-1]
    return("""< xxxx="xxxx://xxxx.com/xxxx//{0}.md">{0} /xxxxxx/""".format(parsed_file))


print(replace_text(test))

with open('results.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in open("test.txt"):
        if line.startswith('file'):
            f.write(replace_text(line) + '\n')
```

Tested on this file:

```
file:///c:/xxxxxxx/nameList.json#/
random crap
more stuff
file:///c:/xxxxxxx/nameList.json#/
file:///c:/xxxxxxx/nameList.json#/
another one
file:///c:/xxxxxxx/nameList.json#/
file:///c:/xxxxxxx/nameList.json#/
file:///c:/xxxxxxx/nameList.json#/
more crap
file:///c:/xxxxxxx/nameList.json#/
file:///c:/xxxxxxx/nameList.json#/
file:///c:/xxxxxxx/nameList.json#/

oooo this is really getting random
file:///c:/xxxxxxx/nameList.json#/
file:///c:/xxxxxxx/nameList.json#/
```

This is the result:

```
< xxxx="xxxx://xxxx.com/xxxx//nameList.md">nameList /xxxxxx/
< xxxx="xxxx://xxxx.com/xxxx//nameList.md">nameList /xxxxxx/
< xxxx="xxxx://xxxx.com/xxxx//nameList.md">nameList /xxxxxx/
< xxxx="xxxx://xxxx.com/xxxx//nameList.md">nameList /xxxxxx/
< xxxx="xxxx://xxxx.com/xxxx//nameList.md">nameList /xxxxxx/
< xxxx="xxxx://xxxx.com/xxxx//nameList.md">nameList /xxxxxx/
< xxxx="xxxx://xxxx.com/xxxx//nameList.md">nameList /xxxxxx/
< xxxx="xxxx://xxxx.com/xxxx//nameList.md">nameList /xxxxxx/
< xxxx="xxxx://xxxx.com/xxxx//nameList.md">nameList /xxxxxx/
< xxxx="xxxx://xxxx.com/xxxx//nameList.md">nameList /xxxxxx/
< xxxx="xxxx://xxxx.com/xxxx//nameList.md">nameList /xxxxxx/
```

Comment: Thx!! Another question: how can I find this line contains "file:///c:/xxxxxxx/nameList.json#/" in my input file?

Comment: Without know more details re: what exactly you're trying to find, I can't really help you.  Searching, spliting and doing things like this is pattern recognition.  What kind of pattern are you trying to find?  what's common among all of your inputs?  Joran's answer might be able to lead you in the right way for finding something like that.

Comment: The common thing is all the lines i want to replace start with "file:

Comment: I really appreciate your help! But when the line contains"file:xxx" is really long, after replacing, it wrapped around :(

Comment: I am sorry, it didnot wrapped around. MY BAD

Comment: Not quite sure what the problem is here.

Comment: In your modified code, does parsed_file = test.split('.')[0].split('/')[-1] suppose to be  parsed_file = s.split('.')[0].split('/')[-1]

Comment: Those two statements are exactly the same.

Comment: So if the line contains"file:xxxxx" is in the middle of the file, by using  f.write(replace_text(line) + '\n') will not replace the line contains file, instead will write a new line with my desired pattern at the end of the file..how should I solve it :)

Comment: @jduan at some point your going to have to figure things out yourself.  Look at the documentation.  Do some research.  I've gotten you close.  You can make it the rest of the way.